# Proguarding a Javafx application using slf4j logger

Tags: javafx, proguard, slf4j, logback-classic

I previously built a Javafx application and successfully wrapped it with proguard, while using java.util.Logger. However, I need to switch from java.util.Logger to the Logger provided by slf4j and use qos-logback. When I use proguard on it, I run into an array of warnings, all generated from either of the slf4j or the qos-logback library. Some of the (MANYYY) warnings are:

- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
- Warning: ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase:
  can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
- Warning: org.slf4j.MDC: can't find referenced method
  'org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder getSingleton()' in program class
  org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
- Warning: org.slf4j.MarkerFactory:
  can't find referenced method 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
  getSingleton()' in program class org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
- Note: ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil accesses a constructor
  '(ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)' dynamically

If you notice, some of the warnings are even repeating. I will be really grateful if anyone can help me out regarding this, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction since I've been stuck on it for a while. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort, I sort of got things done.

I had to add the following to the config:

```
-keep,allowshrinking class ch.qos.logback.core.status.ViewStatusMessagesServletBase {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

I also needed to inspect the warnings to find the source and had to add servlet-api.jar separately as a library.